# Modifications to Apache-Superset via the pip installation?

Tags: apache-superset

So I've recently installed Apache-Superset using the pip installation process given in the official Superset docs https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-from-pypi. I wasn't able to directly download it on to the windows  Machine. But was able to have a workaround. I downloaded Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store and was  able to use the Ubuntu Terminal and install Apache-superset using the pip installation for linux.

So now that I've downloaded it from pip, what i want to know is if or not i can make changes to certain aspects of the code let's say i want to make changes to the UI. Instead of calling it Superset I want to call it StormBreaker for my application. And one more aspect where i want to make changes is let's say We create user's in Apache-Superset using "superset fab create-admin" Command so instead of storing it in some Db i want , Ito give my own Database credentials to store the user info.

Also if i install superset through pip can i use it in production ? Or is the preferred approach for production is Docker Installation?

Thanks for any help I'm still totally new to this Superset, any help or suggestions or advice is appreciated.